# jax-rs code to run on server

Tags: java, rest, restful-authentication, java-server

I have a code which using RESTFul:

```
@Path(/...)
public class ..{
    @GET
    void func(){
        "Hello";
    }
}
```

My question is how to run this code from the browser? I wrote this code in Eclipse and want to run it from browser. How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to start your webservice. To do that you need to pack your application to `WAR` archive and deploy to appserver/servlet container. I suggest [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/). The are both lightweight and have connectors for Eclipse WTP plugin. When your application got deployed to the server, it will be available in your browser. For example if you use Tomcat on 8080 port, and deployed war file named `myws.war` then you webapp is available at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myws/` Then you may navigate to `@Path` urls and call WS methods.

**UPDATE**

Ok, assume you are using Tomcat. [Download](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) zip from their site and unpack somewhere on your system. Then you'll need to configure Tomcat bindings in eclipse. Before it make sure you are using Eclipse for Web developers (with Web Tool Platform installed). Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Server` -> `Runtime Environments`. Click `Add`. Select `Apache` -> `Apache Tomcat 7` and click `Next`. In the popup provide a name for a server (`Apache Tomcat v7.0`) and select it's installation path. JRE will be selected authomaticaly. Click `Finish`. Then choose `Window` -> `Show view` and select `Servers`. Servers view will open. It is empty yet, but we'll add a server. Right-click somewhere on this view and select `New` -> `Server`. Choose `Apache Tomcat v7.0 Server` from list, then set `Server's host name` to `localhost`. Specify any `Server name` and select `Server runtime environment` from dropdown. (It should contain one runtime, which we've created in previous steps). It's done! Now you have a server to run your webapps. Right click on your project and select `Run As` -> `Run on Server`. Select your server, wait for deploy and test your app!

Comment: thanks. I'm beginner so I really didn't understand anything from what you said. Can you explain in more details? I need to use the simplest server, I don't know what is Tomcat or Jetty but I don't need to get complicated in such details, I just need to navigate to @Path and find my application there. What's the code that I need to write in eclipse to do that ?

Comment: You do not need to write any additional code (unless you do not use embedded servers, but you do not). See my updates.

Comment: if you are writing a java web application, tomcat and jetty are certainly not details you can just gloss over.